# Getting ligatures of Qv with Linux Libertine

Tags: fonts, fontspec, ligatures

In old texts in Danish, the letter combination `Qv` was common and more or less worked like `Qu` in English. Now the code

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common}]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}
    Quarante.

    Qvinde.
\end{document}
```

produces a ligature in the letter combination `Qu`, but not in `Qv` (see below). Is it possible to get the lower `Q` to look like the upper `Q` **without having to modify Linux Libertine manually**. I actually assume the answer is "no", but it never hurts to ask.

[image]

Comment: Your assumption is correct, I'm afraid. In order to get the long tail, the Q *must* be followed by u. Make a feature request to the developers of Linux Libertine. On the other hand, I think it's possible to define a “feature file” that defines new ligatures for usage with LuaTex.

Comment: Technically, I guess it would be possible to make some command `\Qtail` which was really `Qu` with the u removed somehow (using some TeX commands), but with the tail taking up no space. However, I am not sure how stable such a solution would be; it might produce bad typography.

Comment: I can't see how it's possible to tweak anything in TeX to get the long tailed 'Q' before a 'v', because the font doesn't provide a long tailed 'Q' as a character at all. It only gives you 'Qu', which is encoded in the font as a single glyph.

Comment: Yes, but I think that you could probably use `tikz` or a similar program to put a white box in front of the `u`, then insert a `v` instead and put it all into the main text. Thus we would get a command `\Qv` where the `Q` had a tail. But it would be an ugly hack and likely cause typographic problems.

Comment: @Gaussler The long tail Q is defined only in combination with u; it's the character with index 2398, “longtail Q+u”.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The long tailed Q is not an independent glyph in Linux Libertine; it is actually bundled with the u in one single character. As a consequence, you have to create the glyph. I'm not an expert on Fontforge, but it is quite straightforward.

1. Go to the font download page in sourceforge and get the source files;
   http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxlibertine/files/linuxlibertine/5.3.0/
2. Open LinLibertine_R.sfd with FontForge
3. Go to the glyph `Q_u` [View > Goto]
4. Select everything in the glyph and copy it
5. Open an empty unicode slot [the one next to the small capital `z`, for instance] and paste it.
6. Select and delete the `u` form
7. Go to the `v` glyph, copy reference it and paste it back on the new unicode slot. Place the referenced `v` accordingly, i.e. with the same distance to the right line as in the `Q_u` glyph. In this case: 15.

[image: Q_v]

8. Open Element > Glyph info and name it `Q_v`
9. Open Element > Font info > Lookups > GSUB > 'liga' Standardligaturen > 'liga' Standardligaturen 1
10. Create a new ligature: On the left row, add `Q_v`. On the right row, add Q, space, v

[image: Qv ligature]

11. Open File > Generate Fonts. Select a directory. Choose OpenType CFF and Force glyph names to TeX. Name it `LinLibertine_R.otf`. Save. Ignore the FontForge complains regarding Extrema points, etc.
12. Create a backup of your system Linux Libertine fonts. Delete the original fonts and replace them with the new ones. To check that it is working.

    `\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
    \begin{document}
        Qvest
    \end{document}`

[image: Sample Qv]

13. Now you have the glyph only for the roman letter. Repeat the instructions for
    a) the Capital small cap+small cap [`Q_u.sc`]
    b) the lower small caps [`q.sc_u.sc`]
14. You're done with the regular file. Now do the same with the italics, the bold, the bold italics and the Display family.

**EDIT 1**

I've modified the regular font (including the small caps of Qv and qv). To do: italics, bold, etc.

[image: Q_v q_v]

**EDIT 2**

Added the metrics:

1. Open Metrics > Kern by Classes > 'kern' Small Caps
2. Search in the first row containing the `v.sc` Class. Add `Q_v.sc` and `q.sc_v.sc` glyphs
3. Repeat with the metrics of Latin and `Q_v`.

[image: Q_v kerning]

Download the regular font [otf & sdf] files [here](http://ge.tt/7ArSNF92/v/0).

Comment: Wow, then it is a lot easier than I thought. Have you in fact already done it (for the non-small cap version), since you provide a screenshot? Can I have the file?

Comment: It works perfectly for me --- in XeLaTeX. But once I switch to LuaLaTeX, it disappears again. Any good idea why?

Comment: And yes, I have run `texhash`.

Comment: @Gaussler. No idea why, because I don't use LuaLatex. On the other hand, I've added a link in the answer to the modified font, including the small caps

Comment: run `luaotfload-tool --update --force`

Comment: @MaxNoe solved the problem!

Comment: @Ludenticus, thank you, it works amazingly!

Comment: @Ludenticus, are you sure you have written everything *exactly* the way it is supposed to be done? Because when I do the same for italics, it does not work. True, I did make one change: I moved the right border line of the Qv glyph a bit to the left to make it all look more natural. However, I cannot see how this should be a problem.

Answer (score 6):

This is ugly like hell and needs a lot of adjustment in order to work. Furthermore, it is likely to produce horrible results in long passages of text and to break down all of the wonderful typesetting features of LaTeX. However, I couldn't miss this chance to prove egreg wrong. :-D

(Even if he obviously already knew this was possible and could do it much more elegantly than I.)

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Ligatures={Common}]{Linux Libertine O}

\newcommand*\Qv{%
\mbox{}%\raisebox{-0.365\height}[0pt][0pt]{%
\raisebox{-0.26\height}[\height][0pt]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt]
    \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (0,0) {Qu};
    \node[fill=white,inner sep=0.5pt] at (3.6,0) {v};
\end{tikzpicture}}\hspace{-3pt}%
}

\begin{document}
    Quarante.

    Qvinde.

    \Qv{}inde.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @egreg Never say never! (In fact, I think you never did.)

Comment: The correct way to do it would probably use some `\hphantom`s or something, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: You aren't removing the “u”, just overpainting it with white. What if the background color is different? `;-)`

Comment: Then I'm in trouble. However, I *very* rarely use other backgrounds than white. But I'm definitely not going to use this in my publication! `;-)`

Comment: It shouldn't be difficult for the maintainers of Linux Libertine to add a `Q_v` glyph and a new stylistic variant for using it on demand.

Comment: @egreg Well, I went to https://sourceforge.net/p/linuxlibertine/feature-requests/ and registered an account, but I could not see any button labeled "new request". How do I add a new one?

Comment: @Gaussler I was also unable to submit a request there once, so I just submitted it as a bug instead: http://sourceforge.net/p/linuxlibertine/bugs/300/

Comment: I already tried sending them an e-mail. We'll see what happens.

Comment: It there should be a good (maybe historical) reason to have that ligature only for `Qu`. Otherwise the font maintainer could have to make it for all the others: `Qe`, `Qt`, etc...

Comment: Well, `u` used to be written `v`, hence in many ancient texts, `Qv` appears. That is a good reason to have this particular ligature (unlike, say, `Qt`, which is probably a rare combination --- I think). That being said, I think the tailed `Q` in general looks better, no matter what follows it, so they should consider adding `Qx` for all `x` in `{letters}`.

Comment: @Gaussler -- Quite the opposite in fact: `u` was usually used for both `u` and `v` until about the seventeenth/eighteenth century. Where a "`v`" was used was when the initial `u` or `v` started the word (e.g., "unde" would usually be written `vnde`; but a word like "universitas" would be written like `vniuersitas`).  I don't mean to suggest it *never* happened, but the vast preponderance of the evidence goes the other way.